# Xamarin Forms - does PopAsync release the popped page?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms app that pushes (and then pops) a new version of the same page class multiple times. Will this create multiple copies of the page in memory, or is each one released/destroyed when it is popped?

Comment: Share your code which you are using to push and pop. Read up on Stack data structure

Comment: If you use the Standard XF navigation, If you add the same page multiple times every time you create a new instance a new page will be created and every time you pop a page the page is removed from memory

Comment: Share the code? Page file ParentPage.xaml.cs calls Navigation.PushAsync(new ChildPage()), and page file ChildPage.xaml.cs calls Navigation.PopAsync().

Answer (score 1):

Per the [implementation](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/NavigationPage.cs#L174), PopAsync **should** discard the page. 
But I believe you may be suffering from the following bug: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1429

This, of course, assumes you are using the "vanilla" Xamarin.Forms.